# Evaluate polynomials with imaginary numbers

Tags: sage

I'm trying to calculate `19v^2 + 49v + 8` to the 67th power over the finite field Z/67Z using Sage where `v = sqrt(-2)`.

Here's what I have so far (using `t` instead of `v`):

```
R.<t> = PolynomialRing(GF(67))
poly = (19 * (t^2) + 49*t + 8)
poly^67
```

This works fine.
But now, I want to evaluate the resulting polynomial with the value `sqrt(-2)`.

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing with a square root of -2 amounts to working modulo
the polynomial t^2 + 2.

The function `power_mod` can be used for that.

Instead of first powering and then reducing modulo t^2 + 2,
which would be wasteful, it performs the whole powering
process modulo t^2 + 2, which is a lot more efficient.

Here are two ways to write the (same) computation.

```py
sage: t = polygen(GF(67))
sage: p = 19 * t^2 + 49 * t + 8
sage: power_mod(p, 67, t^2 + 2)
```

```py
sage: R.<t> = GF(67)[]
sage: p = R([8, 49, 19])
sage: power_mod(p, 67, R([2, 0, 1]))
```